# Pivot control with carousel disabled scrolls headers out of view

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

Our goal is to have 2 sections on this screen and for the user to be able to swipe left/right between them. We do not want the carousel effect where you can keep swiping in one direction forever. To this end, we have set `Pivot.IsHeaderItemsCarouselEnabled = "False"` in our XAML, but this has the  negative side effect shown below. Notice how the beginning of "Available Contracts" scrolls out of view when we swipe to view "My Contracts". How can we present the carousel effect *and* prevent the header area from moving like this? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I have tested Pivot, but I could get this behavior, Could your share more xaml code that I could reproduce this?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT, thanks. Your comment prompted me to test in a blank project and I was able to pinpoint Padding as the problem. See my answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that a Pivot control does not play will with padding. I removed the Padding below and achieved the desired behavior.

```
<Pivot
    Padding="50,25"
    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsGridView"
    AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
    RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"
    RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
    RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
    RelativePanel.Below="errorMessage"
    IsHeaderItemsCarouselEnabled="False"
    TabIndex="1">
```